# Listen on multiple multicast ports

Tags: powershell, multicast

On our phone system, we use multicast for paging.  Occasionally someone will hit the button on accident and we have to fire up Wireshark to track down whodunit.  So I've built a Powershell script to listen for new multicast packets and log them.  Works great, but I can only bind to one port.

I've tried using `Start-Job` and workflows, with no success.  That could fully be on me though.  So... ideas on how to make this listen on multiple ports?

```
$outfile = "c:\multicast log\multicast.txt"

function StartListener{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $IPAddress,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $Port
    )

    $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UDPClient
    $client.ExclusiveAddressUse = $false;
    #$localEp = [System.Net.IPEndPoint]::New([IPAddress]::Any, $Port);
    $localEp = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([System.Net.IPAddress]::Any, $port)
    $remEP = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint([System.Net.IPAddress]::Any,0)

    $client.Client.SetSocketOption([System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel]::Socket, [System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName]::ReuseAddress, $true);
    $client.ExclusiveAddressUse = $false;

    $client.Client.Bind($localEp);
    $multicastaddress = [IPAddress]::Parse($IpAddress);
    $client.JoinMulticastGroup($multicastaddress);

    Write-Host "Listening. This will never quit so you will need to force close it"

    $NewStream = $true
    $last_remEP = ""
    #initialize last_now to something that won't interfere
    $last_now = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)
    while ($true) {
        $receivedbytes = $client.Receive([ref]$remEP);
        $now = Get-Date
        $cur_remEP = $($remEP.ToString())
        if ($last_remEP -eq $cur_remEP) {
            if ($now -gt ($last_now).AddSeconds(1)) {
                $NewStream = $true
            } else {
                $NewStream = $false
            }
        } else {
            $NewStream = $true
        }
        if ($NewStream) {
            $last_remEP = $cur_remEP
            if ((type $outfile).Count -ge 100) {
                (Get-Content $outfile | Select-Object -Skip 25) | Set-Content $outfile
            }
            Add-Content $outfile "$($now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")) - Received multicast from $cur_remEP"
        }
        $last_now = $now
    }
}

Clear-Content $outfile
$now = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"
Add-Content $outfile "$now - multicast logging started"

startlistener 224.0.1.75 50008
startlistener 224.0.1.75 50009

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run listeners on different ports as jobs. You shouldn't have the jobs write to the same file, though, as that might lead to concurrent write attempts. A better approach would be having the jobs write to STDOUT and have your launcher periodically fetch output from the jobs and write it to a file:

```
$addr  = '224.0.1.75'
$ports = ...
$sb = {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Net.IPAddress]$IPAddress,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$Port
    )

    $client = New-Object Net.Sockets.UDPClient
    ...
}

$jobs = foreach ($port in $ports) {
    Start-Job -Name "${addr}:${port}" -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $addr, $port
}

while ($true) {
    $jobs | ForEach-Object {
        $output = Receive-Job -Id $_.Id
        if ($output) {
            "{0}`t{1}" -f $_.Name, $output | Add-Content $outfile
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

---

With that said, wouldn't it be easier to have [WinDump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/docs/manual.htm) trace those packets and rotate the capture files?

Comment: I'd tried pretty much the same script with the start-job, but it never actually started.  I'll adjust a bit with your input and see if I have greater success.  As for WinDump - my output is designed to only write one line per multicast 'session', making it simple to look up the last phone that sent.  WinDump would dump all packets.

Comment: *WinDump would dump all packets.* Not if you filter for specific packets.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify:  WinDump would dump on all packets for a given multicast.  Meaning that for a given phone page I might have hundreds of packets.  Whereas with my script, I'd have one line in my log.

Comment: So... that didn't work.  Despite passing both ports, it actually only starts one job and that one is 'suspended'.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I just ran the above code (scriptblock content slightly adjusted) with 2 ports and got 2 running jobs.

Comment: When you say, you adjusted the scriptblock, are you still using the $client.receive to test with?  And how are you defining $ports?  I'm doing:

$port = @(50008,50009)

Also, I added the open bracket after the foreach-object.

Comment: I removed the `[IPAddress]::Parse($IpAddress)` b/c the parameter definiton already produces an `IPAddress` object, simplified the new stream detection, removed the `Write-Host` statement, and changed the `Add-Content` to `Write-Output`. The ports are defined as `$ports = 50008, 50009`. The missing curly bracket was a typo on my part. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: Would you be willing to update your code above with those changes?  As a note, I didn't originally realize that get-job only worked per PS Session.  So I had a separate PS window open running get-job this whole time and it never turned up anything.  Ignorance for the lose.  Thanks for your continued help, btw.

Comment: Also... I got it to work with your adjustments.  I'd missed the need for the add-content to write-output change.  Thank you for your help!